# how to display image in a grid view or data list?

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

I've uploaded some data and images into the database. I want to retrive them by search button and show the searched values in DataList.

```
     database
        anil               image
        anil k             image
        kishore            image
```

And the WebPage looks like this:

```
     textbox[search button]
```

If Users enters anil in the search box the correspondent name and image should be displayed in DataList.

---

How can I get the data from database and build a DataList from it using asp.net and sql?

Comment: you haven't explained what you exactly. Are you able to fetch the data and just concerned about UI for showing it. Or you want to know how to fetch the data and display it in datalist

Comment: m able to fetch the data m not able to show in a datalist.......@pankaj Upadhyay

Answer (score 0):

If you had a link to click that would open a new window to show the image, you could just return the image directly by changing the page response to stream the image bytes (and change the content type of the response appropriately).  Since you need to display the image within the grid, the only way I can think of doing this (since you can't change the response of the request) is to request all of the files, save it temporarily on the server, and set an image link to the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

this is webforms 101. there are numerous examples online. the "advanced" part is displaying images from a database. but again there are a number of examples on the web about displaying images stored in a database.